# Google Map not displaying on page, no JS errors

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following HTML with a map canvas:

```
   <div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

I have the following jQuery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

console.log(lat_long_vars.latitude);
console.log(lat_long_vars.longditude);

var map;
var map_properties = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long_vars.latitude,lat_long_vars.longditude),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], map_properties);

})
```

I've also included the google maps CDN above my own jQuery.
(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize)

However, the map canvas does not display. The obvious issue might be that the latitude and longitude variables are not set, they definitely are though. Could anyone suggest what the issue could be here? I don't pull back any JS errors.

Comment: I think you should set the width and height of the `map-canvas` div.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- define the height and width of the container for the top level div (in my snippet below that is html/body).
- define the height and width of the `map-canvas` div.

**code snippet:**

```js
var lat_long_vars = {latitude: 42, longditude: -72};
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  console.log(lat_long_vars.latitude);
  console.log(lat_long_vars.longditude);

  var map;
  var map_properties = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long_vars.latitude, lat_long_vars.longditude),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map($('#map-canvas')[0], map_properties);

})
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:100%; width:100%;">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```